# Timestamp compare in Dynamodb DB Query is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In Dynamodb Timestamp compare(Reference: https://www.abhayachauhan.com/2017/12/how-to-store-dates-or-timestamps-in-dynamodb/) is not working as expected.

Dynamod db attributes with one row values :
**id** : "123",
**triggerDate** : "2019-06-07T15:10:18.252Z"

**Not woking case** :
Lets say code executed after "triggerDate" time, to meet "triggerDate" is less than "currentTime"(`triggerDate < :t`).

```
  var currentTime = new Date();
  currentTime = JSON.stringify(currentTime);
  console.log("currentTime:", currentTime);
  let params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :i AND triggerDate < :t",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":t": { S: currentTime },
      ":i": { S: "123"}
    }
  };
  const data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Output**:
`2019-06-08T05:09:02.782Z c4f65ba2-3d3d-43f6-833f-51735bbdcda5    INFO    currentTime: "2019-06-08T05:09:02.781Z"`
`2019-06-08T05:09:03.480Z c4f65ba2-3d3d-43f6-833f-51735bbdcda5    INFO    {"Items":[],"Count":0,"ScannedCount":0}`

Here dynamodb will not return result even though "triggerDate" is less than "currentTime"(`triggerDate < :t`).

**Working Case**: Where currentTime is hardcoded instead of reading from `new Date()` to meet "triggerDate" is less than "currentTime".

```
  let currentTime = "2019-06-08T05:09:02.781Z";
  let params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :i AND triggerDate < :t",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":t": { S: currentTime },
      ":i": { S: "123"}
    }
  };
  const data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Output**:
`2019-06-08T04:35:54.775Z 60f87d6c-0ffb-477a-95ab-cfaec8025d53    INFO    currentTime: "2019-06-08T05:09:02.781Z"`
`2019-06-08T04:35:55.594Z 60f87d6c-0ffb-477a-95ab-cfaec8025d53    INFO    {"Items":[{"id":{"S":"124"},"triggerDate":{"S":"2019-06-07T15:53:54.107Z"}}],"Count":1,"ScannedCount":1}`

Dynamodb will return result here.

Why in **Not working case** dynamodb is not returning any data even though "triggerDate" is less than "currentTime"? 
Is there anything I m missing? 
Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a date object to string using JSON.stringify() is an incorrect way to approach this, and most likely results in bad formatting. Instead, you should convert the date object to string by using the [Date.toISOString() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp).

```
currentTime = currentTime.toISOString();
```